# Time is different between client and server, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Im making a small script just to test the delay for a post request locally and online.

When comparing both dates, i noticed that the time difference was kind of abnormal, the time of the client side is slightly early to what it should be.

```
//server//
app.post('/test', function(req, res){
    res.status(200).json({
            "time" : new Date()
});


//client//
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/test',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data, (new Date()).toISOString());
}});
```

Here is the result :

```
{time: "2019-05-04T15:17:24.571Z"} "2019-05-04T15:17:23.107Z"
```

According to the ajax documentation the res.status trigger the success condition, so the new Date from the client should be superior to the server side time right ?
This only happened when the script is hosted online (google cloud run), its working normally on a local configuration.

Can someone explain me this ?

Comment: Probably the clocks on the two systems are not in sync

Comment: Not possibly. Definitely. Not sure why that's surprising.

Answer (score 2):

It's just that the clocks are out of sync. If you're seeing the time from the server being later than the time in the `success` callback on the client, it means the server's clock is ahead of the client's clock / the client's clock is behind the server's clock.

Note that you can't rely on the client's clock being correct. In situations where it matters, have the server tell you what time it really is (and, obviously, ensure your server's time is synced to a reliable time source like NIST), while allowing for network latency.

---

I did wonder if another explanation could be timezones, but you're doing `.json({"time": new Date()})` and when a `Date` object is serialized to JSON, it creates the string via `toISOString`. Since you're *also* using `toISOString`, both of the dates you're looking at are GMT (with the `Z` timezone indicator), not local. So not timezones.